# usb drive not detected, but is visible in the Disks application. lsusb can see it

Tags: usb, mount, external-hdd

Lenovo IdeaPad
Ubuntu 20.04.2
GNU version 3.36.8

Connected USB drive not accessible, is not displayed
Disks application lists location as /dev/sda

The command 'lsusb' displays 'Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab26 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Slim Portable Drive 1 TB' but the drive is not detected, (does not show up in the side bar) and it is not listed in Nautilus

Comment: Assuming that this is a new drive, have you laid down a fresh MBR/GPT partition table, and created a fresh NTFS or ext2/3/4 partition, using `gparted`? Is this a USB3 drive, and/or connected to a USB3 port? Does the drive work elsewhere?

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l` and `mount`.

Comment: Also assuming it is a new drive but used at least once in a Windows 8 or newer with Fast Startup enabled, it may now be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using the following webpage: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/easily-format-usb-flash-drive-on-ubuntu.html
This directs you to http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mintstick/. The mintstick application link, if you select package installer as the link response will fail. You have to select save to disk, then run the .deb file from Downloads, or wherever it was saved to. Click on the .deb file, and Ubuntu will say it's not compatible. Press install button, anyway, and then you can use it to reformat the misbehaving drives, and all is as it should be.